# Unexpected pixel selected in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I have a simple shader drawing a rectangle in which I want to change color in the fragment shader depending on the fragment coordinate.

A basic implementation binding normalized UVs to vertices works, but I can't get a reliable render. Because whatever I do with the UVs, I can't select the right pixel and sometimes hits a neighbor.

To simplify, let's say I try to draw a sub rectangle playing with UVs like this :

[image]

```c
  uniform vec2 size; // size of the sub rectangle in normalized space
  in vec2 uv;  

  void main() {
    vec2 mask_xy = step(uv, size);
    float mask = mask_xy.x * mask_xy.y;
    color = mix(vec4(1,0,0,1), vec4(0,0,1,1), mask);
}
```

If I ask a specific size let's say (9 * 9) pixels : sometimes I get the right render, and sometimes I get (10 * 9). And it seems to depend on multiple factors :

- the viewport size (would be okay I guess if my normalization was buggy)
- but I also notices render could change by simply moving the rectangle in the window.

The thing is that I get different values on x & y axis despite drawing a square shape, asking for a square size, in a square window. This assymetry is really bugging me.

Notice that the geometry of the rectangle itself is always correct, there is nothing wrong happening with the vertices position.

I tried putting some epsilon value into the step function to avoid rounding errors but I couldn't find any meaningfull pattern.

I tried another approach using gl_FragCoord instead of UVs with an implementation like that :

```c
  uniform vec2 size; // size of the sub rectangle in window space
  uniform vec4 box; // [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax] in window space

  void main() {
    vec2 mask_xy = step(gl_FragCoord.xy - box.xz, size);
    float mask = mask_xy.x * mask_xy.y;
    color = mix(vec4(1,0,0,1), vec4(0,0,1,1), mask);
}
```

gl_FragCoord is supposed to be centered in the pixel, so step should always choose the right boundary.
But even with this implementation, I get the same behavior.

I am running out of ideas to fix this.

Notice that I only tried with this specific renderer (not actually working with the GPU) :

- GL_RENDERER: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 128 bits)
- GL_VENDOR: VMware, Inc.
- GL_VERSION: 3.1 Mesa 18.3.6

Comment: Aim for the middle of the pixel.  If your coordinates are 0.0 or 1.0  aim for 0.5

Comment: @Wyck I misinterpreted the reference of `gl_fragCoord`, adding `.5` seems to resolve the problem with my second implementation, still trying to make the first implementation work though, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I finally got it right with both `gl_FragCoord` and `uv` implementations.

The main problem was lying in the vertices position (the one thing I took for granted ...)

> Notice that the geometry of the rectangle itself is always correct, there is nothing wrong happening with the vertices position.

The solution was to declare the coordinates in window space and use a projection matrix including a normalization factor of `window_size - 1` instead of `window_size`.

This difference had no impact on the output coordinates but it messed up my uv computations with no distinguishable pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know how you set the `uv` coordinates.

Besides that, to avoid rounding errors:

- the step function returns only one of two values, either `0.0` or `1.0`, so instead of `vec2` use `bvec2`
- since we now have boolean values, we can set the type of `mask` to `bool` (instead of a float multiplication, a simple bit-wise `and` will suffice - or just use the function `all`), because
- there exists an overloaded function of `mix`, which returns either the first or the second argument based on the third boolean argument (if the only values are `0` or `1`, there is no point in linear interpolation: `x*(1−a)+y*a`)

But again, since a comparison is involved in the `step` function, it matters how the `uv` coordinates are calculated.

Besides all of that, OpenGL does not guarantee pixel perfect output. It somehow does guarantee the same output if the input is the same (only if the rendering takes place on the very same machine and environment).

Comment: uvs are set in a VBO where bottom-left vertex is assigned (0,0) and top-right is assigned (1,1).
For the mix function, the overload mix(vec4, vec4, bool) is not supported (at least on my implementation). My actual need made me use float instead of bool for convenience but I'll try with simple booleans.

Comment: @Kiwi: You probably specify (0,0) for the top-right corner of the top right pixel. The fragment shader evaluates at the center of the pixel though, so chances are good that the actual coordinates you are evaluating at are (0.25,0.25) for the top-right pixel.